# TJvValidateEdit, Language Settings, Variants and Float Issues

Tags: delphi

In the JvValidateEdit the Value property is a Variant which behaves 
strangely with different Windows Language settings when setting or 
getting a float. If I customize the Windows number formatting for my 
default US settings to comma for decimals and dots for thousands 
separator then the value appears correctly. E.g. a US float of 1.23 is 
displayed as "1,23".

However if I change my Windows Language to Spanish which has the same 
number formatting a real number assigned is now displayed incorrectly.
E.g. The 1.23 value now is displayed as "123".

If I assign a string to the Text ( Ed.Text := FloatToStr ( 1.23 ) it 
appears correctly but if you try and access the number it is reformatted.

When I trace through the code the problem seems to be occurring before 
JvValidateEdit actually starts processing it. It appears the compiler is 
trying convert it to a string in order to assign it to a variant but 
it's doing it wrong. Unfortunately its been a long time since I've 
looked at assembler and that was for an IBM 360.

I'm using XE and generating 32bit code if that makes a difference.

Comment: Try to set the `DisplayFormat` to `dfDecimal` and access the value through the `AsFloat` property. That will internally use `FloatToStr` function for `EditText` value conversion.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of the AsFloat property unfortunately it didn't work any better with the dfDecimal, dfFloat, dfFloatFixed or dfFloatGeneral but I will try and trace into the code and see what's going on since this eliminates the Variant angle.

Comment: What version are you using?  There have been bugs in the JVCL with this; see, e.g., http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/view.php?id=5060.

Comment: Josh: The latest 3.45 but it does appear that this may have been fixed after that release.

Comment: TLama: With dfDecimal and AsFloat it does come in correctly but the output is still wrong. Hopefully the above fix will work.

Comment: @Mitch - For future reference, if you put an "@" before someone's name when replying to them in a comment (like I did here), they'll be notified of your reply.